# Send email to user's email base on user inputs

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5, laravel-4

[image]

I'm trying to send a confirmation email to my user

```
$email   = $inputs['email']; <-------------------------------- HERE
```

---

This block of code is working fine.

```
//Send email to me
$mail = Mail::send('layouts.share.emails.rsvp', array('message' => $message, 'input' => Input::all(), 'ip' => $ip ) , function ($message) {
      $message->from(env('MAIL_USERNAME') , 'bheng gmail');
      $message->to(env('MAIL_TO') , 'LR Wedding\'s Site RSVP ')->subject(' LR Wedding RSVP ');
});
```

---

**I tried**

I am stuck on this block of code.

```
//Send email to user
$mail = Mail::send('layouts.share.emails.thanks', array('message' => $message, 'input' => Input::all(), 'ip' => $ip,'email'=>$email ) , function ($message) {
         $message->from(env('MAIL_USERNAME') , 'bheng gmail');
         $message->to($email, 'LR Wedding\'s Site RSVP ')->subject(' LR Wedding RSVP ');
});
```

I got

> Undefined variable: email

I thought I declared that $email variable already
How do properly do that ?

Comment: where's the code of your html?

Comment: Why is it important ? The error should be in the second of code only.

Comment: it said undefined variable, you have already declared it, i'll just want to make sure that you have a name attribute in your html form that called emal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing `$email` the way you have done passes it to the view, but not to the inner scope of the function.

In order to do that, add `use ($email)` after `function ($message)`.

Example:

```
//Send email to user
$mail = Mail::send('layouts.share.emails.thanks', array('message' => 
$message, 'input' => Input::all(), 'ip' => $ip,'email'=>$email ) , function ($message) use ($email) {
     $message->from(env('MAIL_USERNAME') , 'bheng gmail');
     $message->to($email, 'LR Wedding\'s Site RSVP ')->subject(' LR Wedding 
RSVP ');
});
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/mail#sending-mail

Answer (score 1):

It's possible/likely that your $email variable is outside the scope of the code that is calling it.  Try putting your email variable in the same scope or in the global scope.
For more information about scope in javascript try this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp) .

Comment: how do I do that ? Can you help me out include that as part of your answer ?